# Android, how to determine if a reboot occurred?

Tags: android

How would I programmatically determine when an android device has rebooted (whether on its own, or user initiated) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up a BroadcastReceiver and register it in your manifest to respond to the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED system even. When the phone starts up the code in your broadcastreceiver's onReceive method will run. Make sure it either spawns a separate thread or takes less than 10 seconds, the OS will destroy your broadcastreceiver thread after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet starts an Application automatically after the android-os booted up.

in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** (application-part):

```
// You must hold the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in order to receive this broadcast. 
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
[..]
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
[..]
```

In Java Class

```
 public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);  
            }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a BroadcastReceiver and listen to the broadcast Intent [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED).

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to want to know if the device has been rebooted in-app, then you can use this code.

```
fun hasDeviceBeenRebooted(app: Application): Boolean {
    val REBOOT_PREFS = "reboot prefs"
    val REBOOT_KEY = "reboot key"
    val sharedPrefs = app.getSharedPreferences(REBOOT_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)

    val expectedTimeSinceReboot = sharedPrefs.getLong(REBOOT_KEY, 0)
    val actualTimeSinceReboot = System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() // Timestamp of rebooted time

    sharedPrefs.edit().putLong(REBOOT_KEY, actualTimeSinceReboot).apply()

    return actualTimeSinceReboot !in expectedTimeSinceReboot.minus(2000)..expectedTimeSinceReboot.plus(2000) // 2 Second error range.
}
```