# Have Android app auto start on reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, how to determine if a reboot occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616335/android-how-to-determine-if-a-reboot-occurred)

I have an app that I would like to always be running on my phone.

Is it possible to have an Android app programmatically start after the phone has been power cycled?

Comment: In addition to what CommonsWare said, have a look at this question to see how to launch an `Activity` from a `BroadcastReceiver`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949746/is-it-not-possible-to-start-an-activity-from-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 2):

Add permission android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED to your manifest.  Write a broadcast receiver and add this filter to the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Have your receiver launch any service or perform any task it chooses.

I don't think it's a good idea to try to launch an activity at boot time, but maybe it would work out ok.

Comment: It's irrelevant - Activity does not need to show up, nor even have any UI.

Answer (score 1):

It's an OK idea to have an *app* start after a reboot. It's **not** OK to put an Activity into the foreground after a reboot. Activities should always be under user control. In general, try not to out-guess the users.

However, you may have an interesting use case, so please post it.

Comment: It's ok; OP said "app", not "activity".  It was other posters that mentioned activity.

Comment: There are use cases for running a foreground app on startup. E.g. if you use an Android computer to run a Kioskapp.

Comment: Good point; hadn't thought of that.